# How to add Object to existing Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I am struggling trying to get new data from the reduce method and adding it to an existing array of objects. I have added all of the impressions from delivery.json using the reduce method. What I am trying to do is add it to the placements.json with out changing the actual file. Then map through the new array.

Here is what I can see in my console:

[image]

Here is what I have so far in my code:

```js
// import PlacementData from './components/Placements'
import { Container, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableCell, TableBody, TableRow, Paper } from '@mui/material'

export const Main = ({ delivery, placements }) => {

    const header = ["Name", "Start Date", "End Date", "Impressions", "CPM", "Final Cost"]



    const impSum = delivery.reduce((i, {
        placement_id,
        impressions
    }) => (i[placement_id] = (i[placement_id] || 0) + impressions, i), {})

    let impSumArr = [{ impression: impSum }]

    const advertData = [...impSumArr, ...placements]



    console.log(advertData);
    console.log(impSumArr);





    return (
        <main>
            {/* HEADER */}
            <Container>
                <TableContainer component={Paper} >
                    <Table>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                {header.map((head => { return <TableCell> {head}</TableCell> }))}
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        {/* BODY */}
                        <TableBody>
                            {advertData.map((data) => (

                                <TableRow key={data.id}>
                                    <TableCell> {data.name}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell> {data.start}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell> {data.end}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell> { }</TableCell>  <====== impressions here
                                    <TableCell> {data.cpm}</TableCell>

                                </TableRow>
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            </Container>
        </main>
    );
};
```

placement.json -- I am trying to add my results to this Json file:

```js
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sports",
    "start": "11/1/20",
    "end": "11/30/20",
    "cpm": 5
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Business",
    "start": "12/1/20",
    "end": "12/31/20",
    "cpm": 8
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Travel",
    "start": "11/1/20",
    "end": "11/30/20",
    "cpm": 3
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Politics",
    "start": "12/1/20",
    "end": "12/31/20",
    "cpm": 6
}]
```

delivery.json - This Json file is very large I cut a lot of it out but I added all of the "impression" numbers that had the same "placement_id" together in my impSum variable:

```js
[
    { 
        "placement_id": 1,
        "date": "11/1/2020",
        "impressions": 33427
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 1,
        "date": "11/2/2020",
        "impressions": 30311
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 1,
        "date": "11/3/2020",
        "impressions": 38048
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 1,
        "date": "11/4/2020",
        "impressions": 32167
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 1,
        "date": "11/5/2020",
        "impressions": 38673
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 2,
        "date": "11/6/2020",
        "impressions": 34793
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 2,
        "date": "11/7/2020",
        "impressions": 39949
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 2,
        "date": "11/8/2020",
        "impressions": 37360
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 3,
        "date": "11/9/2020",
        "impressions": 39987
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 3,
        "date": "11/10/2020",
        "impressions": 37955
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 3,
        "date": "11/11/2020",
        "impressions": 31069
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 4,
        "date": "11/12/2020",
        "impressions": 37480
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 4,
        "date": "11/13/2020",
        "impressions": 38894
    },
    { 
        "placement_id": 4,
        "date": "11/14/2020",
        "impressions": 36981
    }
        ]
```

Comment: i dint understood properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you return an array of JSX elements with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can use the second param of the callback as your key (it’s the array item index).

So, instead you could use

```
advertData.map((data, index) =>
  <TableRow key={index}>
```

You’ll need to apply the same pattern to your table header.

For your impressions data, that's easy. You can either leave it as two separate arrays, referencing one by the other (provided the data is in the same order) or create a new array that combines the two.

**Two arrays**

```
const impSum = delivery.reduce((i, {
    placement_id,
    impressions
}) => (i[placement_id] = (i[placement_id] || 0) + impressions, i), {})

...

<TableBody>
    {advertData.map((data) => (

        <TableRow key={data.id}>
            <TableCell> {data.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {data.start}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {data.end}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {impSum[data.id]}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {data.cpm}</TableCell>

        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

**A third new array**

```
const impSum = delivery.reduce((i, {
    placement_id,
    impressions
}) => (i[placement_id] = (i[placement_id] || 0) + impressions, i), {})

const data = placements.map((placement, index) => ({
  ...placement,
  impression: impSum[placement.id]
}))

...

<TableBody>
    {data.map((placement) => (

        <TableRow key={placement.id}>
            <TableCell> {placement.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {placement.start}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {placement.end}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {placement.impression}</TableCell>
            <TableCell> {placement.cpm}</TableCell>

        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Okay, so that fixed my unique key error but I dont understand how to get my the values of my impressions into the TableCell. I need to map through the results I got from my reduce. I figure the easiest way would be to add my placements data with my results like in advertData and then map through. The problem is that I cannot render the results in my index[0] where it says impressions. If I just put {index} where I want my results for impressions to show it will just give me 0-4.

Comment: @Kblack4290 check out my updated answer - I totally missed the impressions problem when answering from mobile

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down! I had the reduce but missing the syntax where the impressions go. Would I be wrong to say that the two array example is the most efficient way out of the two considering it is less code?